# How to do boolean searches of tags in Shotwell?

Tags: search, image-gallery

All my photographs are tagged in Shotwell.   Now I'd like to run a search like "dog and (candle or flame) and not Fort Collins"

I don't see anything in the menu or any right-click popup menu that appears to allow such a thing.   Is this possible?

Of course, it might be useful to also limit the search to before or after some date.